# Error in using menu item to switch between activities in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, menu, menuitem

I am trying to use a menu item to switch between activities in my application. Unfortunately, when I tap on the menu item, it does nothing.

Here is the activity.java code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
// Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Handles Item Selection.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_switch_natural:
            Intent a = new Intent(this, Natural_Display.class);
            startActivity(a);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_switch_natural"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_switch_natural"/>

</menu>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` should be `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, as seen [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond). Don't forget to change `super.onContextItemSelected(item)` to `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to override onCreatecontextMenu before onContextItemSelected.

try this.

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,
 View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

```
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
```

}